# Error message "Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs' "when running the published .exe

Tags: vb.net, exception, download

I've created a little VB.NET console application (using Visual Studio 2019 Commmunity Edition), that automatically downloads a file from the Internet.

The compiled .exe works just fine if I launch it from the Debug directory, inside my Project tree; it does not if I publish the application to a local folder; instead, I get the error message:

```
Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs' from assembly 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection, Version=4.1.2.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

Here's the configuration I use to publish my app:

[image]

Apparently, this is the code generating the exception:

In Program Module:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Module Program
    
     Sub Main(Args() As String)
        
        (...)
    
    End Sub

     
    Sub Download_SpeedTest()
        Dim ooklaWebSite As String
        Dim html As String

        ooklaWebSite = "https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli"

        Try
            ' Retrieve download link
            Console.WriteLine("Getting download link from " & ooklaWebSite)
            html = Get_WebPage(ooklaWebSite)
        
        (...)
        
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred downloading SpeedTest utility. - " & ex.Message)
                    
        End Try
        
    End Sub
```

In WebRequests Module:

```
Imports System.Net

Module WebRequests

    Public Function Get_WebPage(WebURL As String) As String
        Dim sourceString As String
        Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient

        sourceString = wc.DownloadString(WebURL)
        wc.Dispose()

        Return sourceString

    End Function

End Module
```

Here's an example of what I get when I run the published program from Windows Command Line:

```
Getting download link from https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli
An error occurred downloading SpeedTest utility. - Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs' from assembly 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

As per I could see, the exception occurs as soon the function `Get_WebPage` is called (no code inside it is executed)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Trim unused assemblies (in preview)` it sometimes removes assemblies you actually need. You can either turn that off (bloating the file size) or for this particular error, you can add the following to your csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This will make sure that System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll (where System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs is defined) is not trimmed from the final, self-contained binary.